# Calculate the distance of the point p from the affine hyperplane H

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing a linear-algebra course and the question I get is what the distance is from any point p to an affine hyperplane *H* in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by:

$\begin{equation}
H=\{\,h0+\alpha h1+\beta h2\,|\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}\,\}
\end{equation}$

The idea is that I have to make a matlab program that calculates this with inputs $p,h0,h1,h2$. The program itself I can probably make, but I don't understand the formulation and what to calculate exactly.

Comment: The closest point in $H$ to any point $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto $H$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: If you're interested there is a handy formula for that: you can find out on any geometry book. Ps: That formula is valid for Euclidean spaces and it is based on @RcnSc 's idea. If I'm not wrong you don't have concepts such as orthogonality in affine spaces because to define them you need a scalar product between vectors.

Comment: I could find a formula on calculating it, but I don't know what H is if it is denoted like this. are $h0,h1$ and $h2$ vectors or scalars? And what is the formula for H that I need to plug into that equation?

Comment: $h_0$, $h_1$ and $h_2$ are vectors, with $h_1 \neq h_2$, $h_1 \neq 0$ and $h_2 \neq 0$. $H$ is the set of points you can reach from the point $h_0$ by moving in the directions defined by $h_1$ and $h_2$. If $h_1= h_2$ then $H$ is a line and not a hyperplane since you can only move across one direction.

Comment: But can I then make an equation for $H$ when for example the given vectors are: $h0=(1\,1\,1)$, $h1=(1\,2\,1)$, $h2=(1\,1\,2)$: $\sqrt{3}+2x+3y+3z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by first defining a hyperplane through the origin with the vectors $h1$ and $h2$. I then calculated the distance from the point $p$ to that plane and also the distance from the point $h0$ to that plane. Then depending on which side of the plane the points were (on the same side or on the opposite side), I subtracted (same) or added (opposite) the distances.